Can't set two startSpeed constants in Particle System of Unity

That's all you need to reproduce the error:
public ParticleSystem light_ps;

private void Start()
{
    ParticleSystem.MainModule new_main = light_ps.main;
    new_main.startSpeed.constantMax = 10f;
}


I found the answer:
ParticleSystem.MainModule new_main = light_ps.main;
new_main.startSpeed = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(5, 10);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
